# What type of lens should I rent to take pictures of my newly built computer

Tags: canon, computer-hardware, canon-m

I own a Canon EOS M3 and have an EF(-S) to EF-M adapter. Was hoping to take some pictures of the whole rig, but also some internal shots. Would appreciate any suggestions you guys may have in terms of a lens I can rent. Thanks.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, please provide more details.

Comment: A shift perspective or tilt lens sounds ideal if available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just me, but I think the [EF-M 28mm f/3.5 macro IS STM](https://www.lensrentals.com/rent/canon-ef-m-28mm-f3.5-macro-is-stm) lens is probably going to be your best bet, if you want to take closeups. The fact that it has its own built-in LED macro ring light is kinda cool.

You could, of course, also rent the EF-S 60mm f/2.8 USM Macro, or the EF 100mm f/2.8L IS USM Macro, but adapters tend to make everything a bit unwieldy with mirrorless in my book.

Macros not only let you focus closer, but are also sharper than most other lenses when used outside of the macro focus range.

Of course, how you light things is liable to have a far bigger impact on your images than which lens you use.

Comment: Thanks, I went with the 100mm f/2.8L because I didn't want to rely on a tripod as much. I also thought I could use it for some casual portraits since reviews remarked on that positively.